# Parallel optimization with extra parameters (fmincon)

Tags: matlab, optimization, parallel-processing

I have a function 
    f=p1+2*a*c*p2+2*a*b*p3+2*b*c*p4

where

```
p1=-sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2))+sin(((x(4)-   x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(2)-x(1))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(4)-x(3))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)-((x(6)-x(5))/2));
p2=sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2))+sin(((x(4)-x(3))/2)+  ((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(2)-x(1))/2))-sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(4)-x(3))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)-((x(6)-x(5))/2));
p3=sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2))-sin(((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(2)-x(1))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(4)-x(3))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)-((x(6)-x(5))/2));
```

p4=sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2))+sin(((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(2)-x(1))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(4)-x(3))/2))-sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)-((x(6)-x(5))/2));

and x1 until x6 are angles subject to the bound constraint from 0 to pi.

**I want to minimize this function for a range of a=[0:0.01:1] and b=[0:0.01:1]. (That is, I want to minimize this function for each a,b=0, a,b=0.01,a,b=0.02 ... and so on).**

so this my code

**Step 1: Write a file objfun.m.**

```
function f= objfun (x,a,b,c)

a=.57;

b=.57;    % i pick a number for a,b

c=sqrt(1-a*a-b*b);
p1=-sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2))+sin(((x(4)-  x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(2)-x(1))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-  ((x(4)-x(3))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)-((x(6)-x(5))/2));
p2=sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2))+sin(((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(2)-x(1))/2))-sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(4)-x(3))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)-((x(6)-x(5))/2));
p3=sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2))-sin(((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(2)-x(1))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(4)-x(3))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)-((x(6)-x(5))/2));
p4=sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2))+sin(((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(2)-x(1))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(4)-x(3))/2))-sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)-((x(6)-x(5))/2));
f=p1+2*a*c*p2+2*a*b*p3+2*b*c*p4;
```

**Step 2: Invoke constrained optimization routine.**

```
x=[x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5),x(6)]; % angles;
lb=[0,0,0,0,0,0];
ub=[pi,pi,pi,pi,pi,pi];
x0=[pi/8;pi/3;0.7*pi;pi/2;.5;pi/4];
[x,fval]=fmincon(@objfun,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub)
```

**the solution produced is**

```
x=
   2.5530
   0.6431
   2.5305
   0.6195
   2.5531
   0.6421

   fval= -4.3546
```

What would I have to do to run the optimization for a and b ranging from 0:0.01:1, and save the optimal values for each a,b?

Comment: In `objfun`, why do you have inputs for `a` and `b` if you immediately overwrite them?

Comment: This just for one value (fval) as you can see in the result. i want Parallel Computing in Optimization using for loops for a=0, .01,...........1 and b=0, .01,.........1 to have fval matrix (20by20) or (100 by 100) corresponding to a and b

Answer (score 1):

You can find **extensive documentation** on this topic at [Mathworks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html).

Your problem consists of two parts. First, **passing the additional parameters** a and b, which can be done for example **by using anonymous functions** (see above link). This is done like so:

```
f = @(x)objfun(x,a,b);
```

Second, **wrap the function into a for loop** or (if you have the parallel computing toolbox, as I would assume from your title and comment) in a parfor loop.

```
a = 0:0.01:1;
b = 0:0.01:1;
xvals = zeros(length(a), length(b));

for i = 1 : length(a)
    for i = 1 : length(b)
        .
        . invoke your routine here
        .
         f = @(x)objfun(x,a(i),b(i));
         [x,fval]=fmincon(@objfun,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub);
         x_cell{i, j} = x;
         fvals(i, j) = fval;
    end
end
```

After that's done you can access the individual values and parameter sets for example by indexing x_cell{1, 2} for a = 0 and b = 0.01;, similar for fvals, but with round brackets.

**Parallel processing:** Use a parfor loop for the outer loop if that's what you want to do. Do not use it in the inner loop, as it will be slower.

Comment: Thanks for your response. buy you said (invoke your routine here) which one? you already put under what you said. this line  fvals(i, j) = fval; will give me just one big matrix corresponding for all  a,b .

Comment: Could you please help me using parfor loop for parallel processing

Comment: Have a look [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html?refresh=true)

Comment: I tried what you said , but i got an error ... please i need more help

Comment: Do i have to include Parallel Computing Toolbox to run this code even if i use for loops? because the matlab R2015a that i purchased doesn't have Parallel Computing Toolbox ?

Comment: No, the for loop is a basic concept which exists in every Matlab distribution.

Comment: in my problem, there is a normalize condition which is a^2+b^2+c^2=1. how to use IF statement in the code you showed me . can you please  write it again step by step include IF statement

Comment: That sounds like a new question to me. But if you ask one, make sure you include a concise example of what you would like to do.

Comment: Not a new question, but i forgot to mention that a^2+b^2+c^2=1.as i wrote in my question c=sqrt(1-a^2-b^2). so which means we need to put if statement within for loops. could you please help?, I am stuck

Comment: That's not really related to the initial question. So please ask a new one, bearing in mind, though, that you need to provide something that you've tried and that's not working. Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).